# Threads do not start as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I'm trying to make a test to see if someone has certain skills.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class timerup
    {
        public bool timeup = false;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void timer()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    object a;
                    a = true;
                    a = new timerup();
                    timerup ClassRef;
                    ClassRef = (timerup)a;
                    ClassRef.timeup = true;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "The Secret Agent Test";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome, agent. This is the test to see if\nyou are good enough to be a full member of the OT Secret Agency.");
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? [Y/N]");
            string cont = Console.ReadLine();
            if (cont == "y" || cont =="Y")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Let's continue the test.");
                Console.WriteLine("Crack the password:");
                Console.WriteLine("Username: IDIOT_NOOB1337\nPROFILE: Likes memes such as doge.\nIs an elitist (Over the things he likes)\nOnly uses the word idiot as an insult");
                Console.WriteLine("Password:");
                string pass1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (pass1 == "AnyoneWhoDoesn'tLikeDogeIsAnIdiot" || pass1 == "anyonewhodoesn'tlikedogeisanidiot")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Account accessed.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Stage 1 Complete.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading next level...");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Level 2 loaded.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Nice. You certainly have skill. But this test.... determines speed of mind.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You only have two seconds to answer the next question. Press any key when ready.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("What is 12x12?!"); // QUESTION
                    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(timer)); // SUCH COMPLEX CODE FOR A TIMER... WTF.
                    string product = Console.ReadLine();
                    object b;
                    b = true;
                    b = new timerup();
                    timerup ClassRef;
                    ClassRef = (timerup)b;
                    bool timerthing = ClassRef.timeup;
                    if (product != "144" || timerthing == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you are incorrect. Restart the test again.");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.Clear();
                        System.Environment.Exit(-1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Impressive. Your mind is fast, too. Well, be prepared for the next test. Pressure.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thread does not execute; I suspect it is because of the `string product = Console.ReadLine();` bit. The second question of this quiz was 12x12, and you have 2 seconds to answer, except the thread that counted the two seconds wasn't executed... Why...? And if you know, how would I fix it?

Comment: You have create a thread t, but there is no code that calls it, like t.Start().
Put t.Start before ReadLine().

Comment: `t.Start()`. Better yet use `Stopwatch`

Comment: There's quite a bit of code here that doesn't do anything useful (the object reference and the casting), and it probably doesn't do what you expect it to do. `timerthing` will always be false, for example - the `timer` function sets `timeup` to true, but it operates on a different `timerup` instance, so it won't affect the if-else statement.

Comment: Don't use `Environment.Exit`. Simply change your `Main` method's return type to `int` and `return -1;`. And on that note - do not return `-1` when the user fails the game - this is interpreted as an error in the application, and some launchers (like Total Commander) might tell you there was an error starting the application. Just keep the return type `void` and do a simple `return;`.

Comment: Look closely at `for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)  { ... if (i == 5) ... }`

Comment: Please do not put “SOLVED” in your question title; that does not mark the question as answered in the UI. If one of the answers solved your problem, click the green check mark to its left; that will mark your question as answered. If you solved it yourself, type your own answer in below and, after a few days, click its green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some refactoring to your code and solution to your problem :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void WriteText(params string[] lines) { WriteText(0, lines); }

        static void WriteText(double delaySecs, params string[] lines)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
            if (delaySecs > 0) Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delaySecs));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "The Secret Agent Test";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            WriteText("Welcome, agent. This is the test to see if\nyou are good enough to be a full member of the OT Secret Agency.", "Do you want to continue? [Y/N]");
            var readk = Console.ReadKey();
            if (readk.Key == ConsoleKey.Y || readk.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                WriteText("Let's continue the test.\n", "Crack the password:\n", "Username: IDIOT_NOOB1337\nPROFILE: Likes memes such as doge.",
                 "Is an elitist (Over the things he likes)", "Only uses the word idiot as an insult", "Password:");
                string pass1 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (pass1 != "AnyoneWhoDoesn'tLikeDogeIsAnIdiot" && pass1 != "anyonewhodoesn'tlikedogeisanidiot") return;

                WriteText(2, "Account accessed.", "Stage 1 Complete.", "Loading next level...");                
                WriteText(1, "Level 2 loaded.");                
                Console.Clear();
                WriteText(2.5, "Nice. You certainly have skill. But this test.... determines speed of mind.");                
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("You only have two seconds to answer the next question. Press any key when ready.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("What is 12x12?!"); // QUESTION

                int allowedTime = 2 * 1000; // time allowed
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
                    s.Start();
                    while (s.ElapsedMilliseconds < allowedTime) { }
                    WriteText(2, "Sorry, you're too late. Restart the test again.");                    
                    Console.Clear();
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                }).Start();

                string product = Console.ReadLine();
                if (product == "144") Console.WriteLine("Impressive. Your mind is fast, too. Well, be prepared for the next test. Pressure.");

                WriteText(2, "Sorry, you are incorrect. Restart the test again.");                
                Console.Clear();                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You only created a thread. You should also start it.

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(timer);
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wrote this down as an example of how you can check for how long time has passed without using a thread.

```
        bool isInTime = false;

        var start = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("answer this in 5 seconds, what is 2x2");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds <= 5)
            isInTime = true;

        if (isInTime && answer == "4")
            Console.WriteLine("Good job you are now an agent");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("To slow and too dumb");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Stopwatch is another alternative: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

If you really want threads (which are overkill for this problem) there are some good examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The two answers are on the spot, so let me just add how you can create a timer that's not as convoluted :)

```
var timeIsUp = false;
var timer = new Timer(_ => { timeIsUp = true; }, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

But in general, @JensB is absolutely right - using multi-threading should be the *last* option. It's very hard to handle multi-threading properly, so avoiding it is a pretty decent strategy. The `Timer` example I've shown is also multi-threaded - the callback on the timer will occur on a different thread. This introduces synchronization issues, but they shouldn't be too painful for a simple case like this. To improve upon this, you'd at least want to ensure the local is updated safely:

```
var syncObject = new object(); 
var timeIsUp = false;
var timer = new Timer(_ => { lock (syncObject) { timeIsUp = true; } }, null, 5000, 
                      Timeout.Infinite);

var answer = Console.ReadLine();

lock (syncObject)
{
  if (timeIsUp) ...
}
```

Finally, using `Thread` manually is completely unnecessary nowadays. It's much easier to use `Task`s for concurrency and multi-threading. For example:

```
var timerTask = Task.Delay(5000);

var answer = Console.ReadLine();

if (timerTask.IsCompleted) Console.WriteLine("Too late");
```

The best option IMO would be to use proper asynchronous APIs - sadly, the .NET `Console` class doesn't have those. As silly as it is, it seems that this is a pretty decent option:

```
void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    var task = Task.Run(() => ReadLineFromConsole(cts.Token));
    task.Wait(cts.Token);

    if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Too slow!");
        return;
    }

    var result = task.Result;

    if (result != "144")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong!");
        return;
    }

    // Continue
}

public string ReadLineFromConsole(CancellationToken token)
{  
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.In.Peek();

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        ch = Console.In.Read();
        if (ch == -1) return buffer.Length > 0 ? buffer.ToString() : null;

        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') 
        {
            if (ch == '\r' && Console.In.Peek() == '\n') Console.In.Read();
            return buffer.ToString();
        }

        buffer.Append((char)ch);
    }

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Shouldn't be reached, but the compiler doesn't know that.
    return null;
}
```

The interesting point about this approach is that I can exit the application (and abort the input) even if the user doesn't press enter. It also allows you to tie together complex work flows using `await`, although that's slightly tricky in a console application.

The helper method `ReadLineFromConsole` actually works the same as the usual `ReadLine` method, however, it also checks for cancellation, and to prevent it from "stealing" data from later `ReadLine` calls, it will `Peek` first. This doesn't make it thread-safe - you still shouldn't using multiple readlines at the same time from different threads. But it does mean that we can ignore the output when it finally comes. Bear in mind that the thread will be waiting all this time until a console input comes - do not use this to launch multiple simultaneous requests without ensuring there's some input on the way eventually (e.g. using the usual `Console.ReadLine` in between the `ReadLineFromConsole` calls etc.).